# Drools rules logic not working as expected

Tags: drools

*Hierarchy:*
If any employee is paid 100k, Organization.maxSalary = 100k.
If any employee is paid 50k, Organization.maxSalary = 50k if no one else receives 100k.

**DRL**

```
rule "Salary 100000"
    when
        $org: Organization()
        $empDetail: EmployeeDetail() from $org.employeeDetail
        $employee: Employee( $org.maxSalary != 100000,
                             salary == 100000
                           ) from $empDetail.employees
    then
        System.out.println("Salary 100000: " + $org.maxSalary);
        $org.maxSalary = 100000;
end

rule "Salary 50000"
    when
        $org: Organization()
        $empDetail: EmployeeDetail() from $org.employeeDetail
        $employee: Employee( $org.maxSalary != 100000
                          && $org.maxSalary != 50000,
                             salary == 50000
                           ) from $empDetail.milestoneDetails
    then
        System.out.println("Salary 50000: " + $org.maxSalary);
        $org.maxSalary = 50000;
end
```

**Input JSON 1:**

```
{
  "Organization": {
    "EmployeeDetail": {
      "Employees" : [
        {
          "name": "willie"
          "salary": "50000",
        },
        {
          "name": "john"
          "salary": "100000",
        },
        {
          "name": "jack"
          "salary": "50000",
        },
        {
          "name": "jim"
          "salary": "50000",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Expected console output:* `Salary 100000: null`

*Actual console output:* `Salary 100000: null`

All good.

**Input JSON 2:**

```
{
  "Organization": {
    "EmployeeDetail": {
      "Employees" : [
        {
          "name": "willie"
          "salary": "50000",
        },
        {
          "name": "jack"
          "salary": "50000",
        },
        {
          "name": "jim"
          "salary": "50000",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*Expected console output:* `Salary 50000: null`

*Actual console output:*

```
Salary 50000: null
Salary 50000: 50000
Salary 50000: 50000
```

In both cases, the JSON result is good with `Organization.maxSalary` set correctly. But why is the console output weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to fire the rule by checking the org.maxSalary. However you should not check the $org.maxSalary from inside the Employee object, as this is not an Eployee's property but Orgranization's.

Also, after setting the maxSalary on org, you should **update** the Organization fact with the new value (maxSalary). `update()` makes the rules engine aware that a fact has been modified.

Here is the complete rules code

```
rule "Salary 100000"
    when
        $org: Organization(maxSalary != 100000)
        $empDetail: EmployeeDetail() from $org.employeeDetail
        $employee: Employee( salary == 100000
                           ) from $empDetail.employees
    then
        System.out.println("Salary 100000: " + $org.maxSalary);
        $org.maxSalary = 100000;
        update($org);
end

rule "Salary 50000"
    when
        $org: Organization(maxSalary != 100000 && maxSalary != 50000)
        $empDetail: EmployeeDetail() from $org.employeeDetail
        $employee: Employee(
                             salary == 50000
                           ) from $empDetail.employees
    then
        System.out.println("Salary 50000: " + $org.maxSalary);
        $org.maxSalary = 50000;
        update($org);

end
```

Output on the Json2 is

```
Salary 50000: null
```

I also do not understand the logic of having

```
 System.out.println("Salary 50000: " + $org.maxSalary);
 $org.maxSalary = 50000;
```

instead of

```
 $org.maxSalary = 50000;
 System.out.println("Salary 50000: " + $org.maxSalary);
```

It seems weird to first print an empty maxSalary and then assign the amount to maxSalary.

Comment: Here is the output for the code you've provided which is even weirder: Salary 100000: null; Salary 50000: 100000; Salary 50000: 50000; Salary 50000: 50000; And the $org.maxSalary is set incorrectly as 50000.The System.out and the code I posted here is not my actual use case. This is just an example to illustrate the weirdness I've encountered and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: What is the difference betweeen $empDetail.milestoneDetails and $empDetail.employees ? Also what type is the salary and maxSalary? Are they Strings? I will try to run your code.  `Salary 50000: null` maxSalary is not primitive, is it an Object holding numbers or String?

Comment: I missed the update($org) statement. I updated my answer, check this out :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much.